# .NET 6: synchronous operations are disallowed. Call WriteAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I have implemented a console application in .NET 6.0. I have already AllowSynchronousIO = true in startup but still getting the same error. Below is  code that i have added in the startup class to allow synchronous to true.

```
    services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
    });
```

Comment: `console application` doesn't have `IISServerOptions` and `startup class`. I think you are talking about `web application`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `CreateHostBuilder` (Program.cs) add this

```
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(builder =>
{
    builder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
    {
        options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
    });
    builder.UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Not sure how to do that with minimal API